# Templates when using vectors instead of doubles as input

Tags: c++, templates, casting, operator-overloading

I am trying to achieve a very simple thing using C++ templates. I would like to build a generic sign function that could handle the case `sgn(x)`where x could be either `double`or `std::vector<double>` (that is returning a `std::vector<double>` containing the results). In order to achieve that I am using templates

```cpp
double f(double x) {
    return (x>=0)?1.0:-1.0;
};

template<typename T>
T F(T x) {
   // ?
};
```

I would like to cast the template and either use `f` if `double` or a `for` loop if `std::vector<double>`. Unfortunately my function does not use any arithmetic operator and the conditional operator cannot be overloaded. How should I proceed ?

Comment: Why use templates here? You should overload the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While overloading is the best way to achieve what you want, it is not
really the way to work with the C++ standard library.

If you want to apply a function to all elements of a container (either
mutating them or creating new results), use `std::transform` or
`std::for_each` with the function you want to use.

```
std::vector<double> doubles, results;
std::transform(begin(doubles), end(doubles), std::back_inserter(results), sgn);
```

That separates concern far better than your current approach. Only
operate on whole containers if it is really required, in all other
cases use iterators and higher-order functions.

Comment: Thanks, I won't have to reinvent the wheel here. Applying a function to a vector is what I needed, templates are useless for that purpose.

Comment: @vanna Well, `transform` et al **are** templates. They are perfect for that purpose.

Answer (score 3):

This is solved by overloading, not templates.

```
double sign(double x) {
    return x < 0.0 ? -1.0 :
           x > 0.0 ?  1.0 : 0.0;
};

std::vector<double> sign(std::vector<double> const& x) {
    // ?
};
```

That said, I’d doubt whether a `sign` function is meaningful for vectors.

This, by the way, has got nothing to do with “arithmetic” versus “non-arithmetic” functions, as alleged in the title of the question. This distinction doesn’t exist in C++.

Comment: Thanks for noticing my error in the sign function. As pointed out I do not need any templates here, overloading will do fine. Just got confused here.